# Desvincular funções dos 'botões' em PHP

Tags: php, button

Gostaria de desvincular os botões, tenho um botão de gerar senha e um de chamar, mas toda vez que gero uma senha, ele também chama, gostaria de desvincular esses botões, alguém poderia me ajudar por gentileza?

```
  <?php
  echo "<form>";
  echo "<button> Gerar senha</button>";
  echo "</form>";
  $letras = range('A', 'Z');
  $numeros = range(1, 9);
  shuffle($letras);
  shuffle($numeros);
  $senha = implode('', array_slice($letras, 3, 3)) . '-' . 
  end($numeros);
  $file = 'senhas.txt';
  if (!$handleFile = fopen($file, "a+")) {
  die("<p>Erro ao abrir/criar o arquivo: (<b>$file</b>) 
  </p>");
  }
  fwrite($handleFile, $senha . "\r\n");
  fclose($handleFile);
  $arr = (file_get_contents($file));
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($arr);
  echo '</pre>';
  echo "<hr>";
  ?>
  <?php
  echo "<form>";
  echo "<button> Chamar senha</button>";
  echo "</form>";
  print_r("Senha $senha dirija-se ao caixa de atendimento");
  ?>
```

Comment: Bruno eu não entendi muito bem a pergunta, mas vou responder o que acho que entendi. O seu código está todo global, então ele é executado independentemente de apertar o botão, certo? O que você podia fazer é colocar os botões para responder a eventos com JavaScript, e assim chamar as funções PHP com a lógica de cada um. Para o que eu estou sugerindo precisa de algumas coisas mais complexas para resolver isso, como requisições Ajax. Você teria que criar arquivos separados para a lógica PHP e para a página HTML. [Veja essa resposta com um exemplo para resolver o seu problema.](https://stackoverf